# JOptionPane inside while loop

Tags: java, while-loop, joptionpane

My Pop-up message is not showing even though i think i used JOptionPane Correctly inside the while loop. please help. The code is Java btw

```
import java.util.*;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class Plotpjestueshmeria {
public static void main(String[]args){

    
    Scanner in= new Scanner(System.in); 
        int p;
        int x;
        int z;
        
        
        
        System.out.print("Type a number:");
        x=in.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Numbers which " + x + " is divisible by, are:");
        
        for(p=1; p<=x;++p)
            {
            if(x%p==0)
                System.out.println(p);
            }
        
        System.out.print("Type a number you want to check:");
            z=in.nextInt();
            while(x%z==0)
            {
                
                int answer=JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Do you want to pick another number?");
                System.out.println("Your number IS on the list!");
                        if(answer==0)
                        {
                            System.out.println("Pick another number:");
                            z=in.nextInt(); 
                        }

                        else if(answer==1 )
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Have a great day! :)" );
                        else if(answer==2)
                            System.exit(0);
            
            } 
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Your number is NOT on the list! \n Pick another number." );
            
            z=in.nextInt();
            {
            while(x%z==0)
            
                System.out.println("Your number IS on the list!");
                int answer=JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Your number IS on the list! \n Do you want to pick another number?");
                
                        if(answer==0)
                        {
                            System.out.println("Pick another number:");
                            z=in.nextInt(); 
                        }

                        else if(answer==1 )
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Have a great day! :)" );
                        else if(answer==2)
                            System.exit(0);
            
            }   

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Your number is NOT on the list! \n Have a great day! :)"); 
                System.exit(0);
            
        
    }

}
```

Comment: Edit: I am required to finish this task in the next 2 hours.

Comment: *My Pop-up message is not showing* - what message? You have multiple uses of JOptionPane.